# Render simple array using Mustache.Js

Tags: arrays, mustache

Having a array like below

`var arrNames = ["Stackoverflow","StackExchange","Webmaster","Programmers"];`

how should  a template look for working with mustache.js javascript template. I tried below but no clues

- `{{#}}{{key}}{{/}}`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/):

> When looping over an array of strings, a . can be used to refer to the current item in the list.
>
> Template:
>
> > {{#musketeers}}
> >     * {{.}}
> >     {{/musketeers}}
>
> View:
>
> > {
> >      "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
> >     }
>
> Output:
>
> > - Athos
> > - Aramis
> > - Porthos
> > - D'Artagnan

```js
var tpl = document.getElementById('simple').innerHTML,
  view = {
    items: ['Stackoverflow', 'StackExchange', 'Webmaster', 'Programmers']
  };

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = Mustache.to_html(tpl, view);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
<script type="template" id="simple">
  <h1>Array Values</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#items}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/items}}
  </ul>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer! I was struggling to find it.

Comment: The fiddle seems to output nothing.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev updated to include runnable snippet here instead of jsFiddle