# Set data inside of the div based on table cell id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables on my screen. Each table is in a separate div container. After ajax call I have logic that will check for container ID and loop through each table td. I have two tables where I have to set the data inside of the div that is warped in td cell. Here is my example:

```
<div id="container1">
    <table class="tblData">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" id="a1_comment"><div class="textScroll" id="a1_comment2" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:140px;"></div></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <table class="tblData">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" id="a2_comment"><div class="textScroll" id="a2_comment2" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:140px;"></div></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$('#'+tabID+' table tr td').each(function(){
    var value = $.trim(decodeURIComponent(obj.DATA[$(this).prop('id').toUpperCase()]));
    var id = ((tabID == 'container1' && $(this).prop('id') == 'a1_comment') || (tabID == 'container2' && $(this).prop('id') == 'a2_comment')) ? $('.textScroll') : $(this);
    id.text(value).css({'color':'blue','font-weight':'bold'});
});
```

Code above was checking if it's container 1 or 2 and then checked for specified id. In that case data was set to element based on class. That will cause some problems in case where data from one container will show in the other. To prevent that I would like to use div id in each container. Is there a simple way to do that in JQuery?

If `container1` and id eqials `a1_comment` then set data in div with id `a1_comment2`. Other way around for container 2.

Here is example for DATA object that is returned after Ajax call:

This is for container 1: `DATA":{"A1_COMMENT":"Some data"}`

Container 2: `DATA":{"A2_COMMENT":"Some data"}`

Each container is populated from separate Ajax call/function on the server side.

Comment: For having such an issue, I think you are approaching this in a wrong way. Can't you map the data from the ajax call to each table, and then traverse 'safely' inside of it? This way you can not fill data in the wrong table...

Comment: is this only for the two divs `a1 / a2` or any divs with some IDs ? where is the data you need to put in the specific div (or where does it come from) ?

Comment: @OldPadawan I have only two div's so far that need to be populated. In the future there might be more. That is a reason why I'm looking for the best possible solution.

Comment: i would use some template engine with multidimensional arrays for this task.

Comment: @Ursache Can you provide some example or general idea?

Comment: wouldn't you use a `data-id` attribute (with *unique* ID) for each div, then populate response according to its ID ?

Comment: @espresso_coffee this is only a general idea: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/elements/dom-repeat

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm looping through table cell ID's but my guess is that might be an option.

Comment: more examples: [mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045768/render-simple-array-using-mustache-js) [angular](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp)